# When making third party call from product cockpit while creating a new item

Tags: e-commerce, sap-commerce-cloud

I am trying to make a third party call while creating product from productcockpit.I have overridden onCreateEvent method. I facing a problem while creating a product. There are two calls triggered when creating a product, I am unable to find difference between the calls.

Comment: Could you describe your problem more specifically or put some code? Because i don't understand what is the issue and what is your expected result.

Answer (score 1):

I would look at a PrepareInterceptor for this perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the PrepareInterceptor, please see https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/Interceptors for more information.